# Asyncio wait for TimerHandle

Tags: python, python-asyncio

It seems that `TimerHandle` is not awaitable. What is preferred way to wait for all callbacks scheduled using `asyncio.call_later` assuming I have all `TimerHandle`s.

Comment: Seems to be an overkill (or at least too complicated) but I'm using `asyncio.Event` that I clear when I call `call_later` and set in callback. And then I wait in while until there is any handler (clearing event before `event.wait`).

Comment: You can use an `asyncio.Future` (obtained with `loop.create_future()` for the same purpose. It's more lightweight than an event, and it can carry an object as payload, or even an exception.

Comment: Could you give an example how you would use `Feature` for many timers? I suggest an ordinary response, not a a comment;)

Comment: It's `Future`, not `Feature`. If you need to clear the event and wait for it again, then I guess it can't be replaced by `Future`. I understood you needed to wait for the individual callback.

Comment: Sure it's `Future` - my mistake:) OK. I've been thinking about `Future`s and maybe an option would be to create a `Future` per timer and then wait for all. Maybe. Is it less complicated? Maybe...

Comment: Yes - your wrapped callback must end with `futureobj.set_result(None)`, and you wait for the futures by just `await`ing them (or `await gather(list_of_futures)` to wait for all of them, etc). The nice thing is that a `Future` is more lightweight than an event - it is a fundamental building block in asyncio. Events themselves are implemented in terms of futures, as are many other things in asyncio. (Take a look at the [implementation of `asyncio.sleep`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bc854750589d4de0fd55693963964e0558b5c8ac/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L581) for an example.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've taken a look into how `asyncio.sleep` is implemented and it turns out that it creates an internal `Future` and runs `call_later`. So based on this I've come to conclusion that best option would be to create a coroutine and use it like this:

```
async def set_timer(seconds):
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    do_something_important()

timer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(set_timer(10))
timers.append(timer_task)
...
await asyncio.gather(*timers)
```